# Sort by second parameter and iterate in order

Tags: java

I have a Linkedhasmap and have key and values

Now i want to sort the map by values and the key and value should appear as follows

```
Example,
 Key    Value
  1      0.0
  2      0.2
  3      0.5
  4      0.0
  5      0.3
  6      0.0
  7      0.1

Expected output
  1      0.0
  4      0.0
  6      0.0
  7      0.1
  2      0.2
  5      0.3
  3      0.5
```

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values)

Comment: No. I am talking about sorting the linkedhashmap

Comment: LinkedHashMap always has insertion order. This cannot be changed. Ergo you need to create a new LinkedHashMap with items inserted by increasing value. This can be done using the steps in the question and answers I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot sort on Linkedhasmap, but you can put entries into the List and sort the List. After clearing Linkedhasmap, you can put your entries.